# MySQL: Best way to update a large table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table with huge amount of data. The source of data is an external api. Every few hours, I need to sync the database so that the changes are up to date from the external api. I am doing a full sync (api doesn't allow delta sync).

While sync happens, I want to make sure that the data from the database is also available for read. So, I am following below steps:

1. I have a cloumn in the table which acts as a flag for whether or not data is readable. Only the data with flag set is marked for read.
2. I am inserting all the data from the api into the table.
3. Once all the data is written, I am deleting all the data in the table with flag set.
4. After deletion, I am updating the table and setting the flag for all the rows.

Table has around ~50 million rows and is expected to grow. There is a customerId field in the table. Sync usually happens based on customerId by passing it to the api.

My problem is, step 3 and 4 above are taking a lot of time. Queries are something like:

Step 3 --> `delete from foo where customer_id=12345678 and flag=1`

Step 4 --> `update foo set flag=1 where customer_id=12345678`

I have tried partitioning the table based on customer_id and it works great where customer_id has less number of rows but for some customer_id, the number of rows in each partition itself goes till ~5 million.

Around 90% of data doesn't change between two syncs. How can I make this fast?

I was thinking of using just the update queries instead of insert queries and then check if there was any update. If not, I can issue an insert query for the same row. This way any updates will be taken care of along with the insert. But I am not sure if the operation will block read queries for this while update is in progress.

Comment: Does this api return timestamp of each item last change?

Comment: And regarding the approach with partitions, how did you do the deletes? By droping the whole customer partition or ordinary select?

Comment: @agarwalankur85  If I understand it correctly, the table is read only (to the users, not the api and your flag of course) and all rows are completely reinserted to the table by the api? Could you define a different table as a destination for your api inserts (where the api writes to, and from which you could move the rows to the real table)? And since you are currently having a period of time where 0 rows are readable (between 3 and 4), I assume that a (short) amount of downtime would be acceptable? And last but not least: what is your mysql version?

Comment: @Solarflare - I am not sure, how writing to a different table and then moving the data helps here. From what I understand, this will still require step 3 and 4 on existing table.
About downtime - idea is to reduce the time in step 3 and 4. Currently it takes up to an hour for each operation.
MySql version ins 5.7

Comment: @krasipenkov - api does not return timestamp. About the deletion, I did ordinary delete just like it is in the 3 and 4th step. If I drop the partition, data for that partition will not be available for read until sync completes.

Comment: @agarwalankur85 No, it (maybe) won't require step 3 and 4, that is why I am asking. Do you have any foreign keys to or from that table?

Comment: @Solarflare - I don't have any foreign key to or from that table

Answer (score 1):

For your setup (read only data, full sync), the fastest way to update the table is to not update at all, but to import the data into a different table and to rename it afterwards to make it the new table.

Create a table like your original table, e.g. use

```
create table foo_import like foo;
```

If you have e.g. triggers, add them too.

From now on, let the import api write its (full) sync to this new table.

After a sync is done, swap the two tables:

```
RENAME TABLE foo TO foo_tmp, 
    foo_import TO foo, 
    foo_tmp to foo_import;
```

It will (literally) just require a second.

This command is atomic: it will wait for transactions that access these tables to finish, it will not present a situation where there is no table `foo` and it will completely fail (and not do anything) if one of the tables doesn't exist or `foo_tmp` already exists.

As a final step, empty your import table (that now contains your old data) to be ready for your next import:

```
truncate foo_import;
```

This will again just require a second.

The rest of your querys probably assume that `flag=1`. Until (if at all) you update the code to not use the flag anymore, you can set its default value to `1` to keep it compatible, e.g. use

```
alter table foo modify column flag tinyint default 1;
```

Since you don't have foreign keys, it doesn't have to bother you, but for others with a similar problem it might be useful to know that foreign keys will get adjusted, so foreign keys that are referencing `foo` will reference `foo_import` after renaming the tables. To make them point to the new table `foo` again, they have to be dropped and recreated. Everything else (e.g. views, queries, procedures) will resolve by the current name, so they will always access the current `foo`.

Comment: Comming to think about it: you didn't directly answer my question if all rows that are in the original table are completely reinserted in an import or not, and I assumed here they are. If you only update specific customers, this approach will not directly work, but you can do the same logic using partitions (you can swap partitions similar to renaming tables), it would require your to partition by customer id. It would be best if you have a fixed number of customers, but you can use it just for the big ones (and update the small ones as right now).

Comment: Thanks Solarflare. Not all the rows are completely replaced. They are updated based on customer_id. At a time, full sync is run for a customer and not for all the rows in that table. I am going to try your approach of swapping partitions. Number of customers are not fixed.

Comment: Performance is likely to to suffer with more than, say, 50 partitions.  So, think about `PARTITION BY RANG(customer_id)`, but have only the biggest 20 in partitions by themselves.  Maintenance will be tricky.

Comment: I ended up using http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html to avoid delete and update. The solution from @Solarflare worked too when I have partition based on ranges instead of hash partition. I couldn't get a way to get the partition in which the data has to be deleted with Hash partitioning. In either case, insert on duplicate was fastest and without any downtime. It did require me to create unique primary key based on combination of some fields in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
Load `new` by whatever means you have; take as long as needed.
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

The `RENAME` is atomic and "instantaneous"; `real` is "always" available.

(I don't see the need for `flag`.)

**OR...**

Since you are actually updating a chunk of a table, consider these...

If the chunk is small...

1. Load the new data into a tmp table
2. DELETE the old rows
3. INSERT ... SELECT ... to move the new rows in.  (Having the new data already in a table is probably the fastest way to achieve this.)

If the chunk is big, and you don't want to lock the table for "too long", there are some other tricks.  But first, is there some form of unique row number for each row for the customer?  (I'm thinking about batch-moving a bunch or rows at a time, but need more specifics before spelling it out.)

Comment: Problem here is that, sync happens for one customer at a time. So I can not  drop the older table.

Comment: No. There is only row id (set to auto-increment). Problem is with the large sized customer. It takes close to 4-5 minutes (with partitioning) to delete all the rows for a customer.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It will give me some specifics to talk around.